# Is it possible to remove entries/prevent entries being added to a legend with FSharp.Charting?

Tags: f#, fsharpchart

I'm making time series plots with FSharp.Charting.FastLine. I only want to highlight some of the lines in the legend. This requires removing entries from the legend, or preventing some lines being added to the legend. Is this possible? the current code looks like the following. I tried making two charts, one with a legend and one without and combining them, but that didn't seem to work. So, is there any way I can control/edit the entries in the legend?

```
Data
|> Array.map (fun dataForLine -> Chart.FastLine(dataForLine,Name='Name'))
|> Chart.Combine
|> Chart.WithLegend
```